# svn: any way to efficiently list which properties have changed

Tags: svn, properties

`svn diff` doesn't seem to have a way to just list the property names (not values) that have changed. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`svn diff` itself seems not to have an option to allow that. So you could add a filter, to only list changes with a special format (depending on the OS you are using easy or no). In Ruby, I would match like that:

```
/(Property .*\n_+\n(.*\n)+)\n\n)/
```

Reads like that:

- Starts with `Property` to the end of line.
- Then full line with `______`.
- Then anything, up to 2 line breaks.

An example could be:

```
Property changes on: summary.xls\n
___________________________________________________________________\n
Modified: svn:mime-type\n
   - application/octet-stream\n
   + application/excel\n
Added: svn:needs-ok\n
   + *\n
\n
```